# Multiple jars in a single aws lambda layer

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I have a Java 11 lambda. It uses classes in jars that are in a layer attached to the function. The layer has a zip with the following structure based on [aws lambda developer guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html#configuration-layers-path):

```
java/
  - lib/
    - a.jar
    - b.jar
```

The jvm running the lambda can't find the classes in those jars and fails with
`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`.

I also tried the following structure in the zip file:

```
lib/
  - a.jar
  - b.jar
```

Comment: Is the error actually about any class that is in those Jars? It might be for a totally different class that never was in those Jars.

Comment: I have verified with zipinfo that the class is present in one of those jars.

Comment: @Jens your comment made me check the logs again. I found that there's a class that's missing from the zipped jars. The log entry is near the beginning. I have a lead now. Thank you!